# How to delete the formula in a cell using an IF statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and can't figure out how to delete the formula in a cell if it doesn't meet a certain criteria. I want to delete the formula (leaving the cell totally blank) if the value that the formula has as an output is greater than 0. The formula I want to delete in these cells is: =IF(A1>0,A1,""). So if the outcome of that formula is less than zero, nothing will show up in the cell (and if it is greater than 0, then the actual number will appear - I'm trying to hide negative numbers), but the formula is still there and I want to remove the formula with this macro.

I recorded a macro to see the general code to delete a cell's contents, but when I put it into an IF statement, it doesn't seem to work. When I click the 'Delete' button on a cell, VBA correlates that with Selection.ClearContents.

```
Sub DeleteCell()

If Range("B1").Value < 0 Then Range("B1").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Do I have to indicate somewhere that IF the formula's output is less than 0, it should delete the contents? When I do the above code, it runs but the formulas stay in the cells.

Comment: `If Range("B1").Value = "" Then Range("B1").ClearContents`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you so much!